# ¿Cuáles temas sexuales son apropiados y cuáles son los estándares cuando se habla de ellos?

Tags: discusión, convenciones-sociales

Poder comprender e implementar léxico sexual es un aspecto importante de hablar con fluidez en cualquier idioma. Por eso de seguro tendremos una discusión que trate de y/o que use palabras sexuales.

Quiero establecer dos cosas:

- **¿Cuáles temas se consideran necesarios y apropiados y cuáles temas se consideran groseros y ofensivos?** P. ej., jerga, terminología médica, diferencias regionales.
- **¿Cuáles son los estándares cuando se habla de los temas apropiados?** P. ej., siempre usar lenguaje formal, censurar (parcialmente o completamente) palabras/frases explícitas.

*(Si les importa, pregunto esto porque quisiera publicar una pregunta que pide interjecciones sexuales.)*

Comment: Hola Chase, ¿podrías ser un poco más específico? En general podemos asumir que todos somos adultos y maduros, por lo que se puede utilizar todo aquel vocabulario que sea pertinente sin que nadie se lleve las manos a la cabeza.

Comment: Hola @fedorqui , supongo que lenguaje gráfico tal vez podría desencadenar a una persona que ha tenido que padecer un trauma así que hay un protocolo para mantener un ambiente positivo en el sitio. No sé si eso contesta su pregunta. Básicamente quiero saber qué necesito hacer para que mis preguntas sobre léxico sexual no sean *flagged* ni cerradas. ¿Le hago sentido?

Comment: Se te ve una persona respetuosa y con sentido común, por lo que me atrevo a afirmar que tu pregunta será así y no va a herir sensibilidades. Si quieres ser más específico puedes comentárnoslo por el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia) o incluso escribirme un correo electrónico a la dirección que aparece en mi perfil. Pero vaya, no temas.

Answer (score 1):

Particularmente creo que los límites han de ser los impuestos por la política de Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow en general. Por pura supervivencia.

Este stack forma parte de una red más grande, que se rige por las leyes de Estados Unidos, y que imagino que tendrá definidos ciertos criterios en cuanto al acceso y uso por parte de menores de edad, y en cuanto a la publicación de contenidos no apropiados.

Yo en España puedo ser muy libre de poner una pregunta pidiendo una traducción del fragmento de *El diario de Anna Frank* en el que la niña explora su vulva, vagina y clítoris frente al espejo. Pero en Estados Unidos [hay gente muy sensible con esos temas](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2013/may/07/anne-frank-diary-us-schools-censorship), y no me extrañaría que existiesen, si no leyes a nivel estatal (tiempo al tiempo), sí políticas muy definidas al respecto en sitios como Stack Exchange.

Por supuesto, sería de ilusos esperar que todos los usuarios se conozcan al 100% la legislación estadounidense o las políticas de SE sobre publicación de contenido de índole sexual. Por eso creo que corresponde a los moderadores el estar atentos para que las referencias a temas sexuales no violen ninguna política de SE ni puedan suponer un perjuicio para Spanish.SE (nadie quiere que cierren el stack por mensajes inadecuados).

Dentro de esos límites, y siendo todos lo más cívicos posible, lo que se quiera.

Answer (score 0):

Cualquier tema sexual debería ser permitido en el ámbito puramente informativo cuando es referente al uso del lenguaje.

Artístico, histórico o médico. No debería haber razones para censurarlo.

Como dice el viejo dicho: Uno es responsable de lo que dice, no de lo que la gente piensa.

Aunque podemos encontrarnos con progresistas que tratarán de defender la sensibilidad de algunas personas, la censura sin sentido únicamente provoca un desprendimiento enfermizo de la realidad.

Únicamente debería ser censurado o incluso bloqueado cuando rompa con el objetivo del grupo, el cual es: "el español".